# clear graphics in child page from parent (created using 'data' html tag)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window, parent-child

I have seen questions similar to but not quite the same as this here at SO:::

In my webapp, a 'child' window is created from the parent on a button click with this html:

```
<div style='width:100%;  height:100%'><object type="text/html" name ="mapPage" style='width:100%;  height:100%' data='mapPage.html'>

            </object></div>
```

I would like to run another function from the parent page with a button click that will clear graphics from the child page.  How ca I do this? Since I am not using 'window.open' to create the child, I don't think I can approach this in that way? I am also not using iFrames so I believe 'window.parent' or something along those lines is also not an option ...
ideas? thanks, Jason

Comment: I actually don't know what `object` does, is it like `iframe`? `iframe`s can do what you want since you can have a reference to the document and all elements in it.

Comment: I was told by our web specialists here that iFrames are good to avoid, b/c of cross browser compatibility issues and other inconsistencies....